# Punch a face on a model to the first backface of the model and make a hole

Tags: mesh, modifiers, edit-mode, workflow, faces

I have a model where i need to make a lot of holes. The kind of the problem is in all of them the same. The position and size of the hole(s) is already set by a face and they should not change. So what i need to do is to punch the face through the part of the model to a backface.
Here is an simplified illustration of the problem:

[image: simplified problem]
[image: different perspective of the problem]

Update1: I don't have a separate mesh to make holes.

Update2: I have this problem probably more than 30 times in my mesh. So doing an extrusion, deleting backface, punching hole, recreating the backfaces, making the tunnel is unpythonic. Is there a shortcut for this?

Comment: The difference is i don't have a separate mesh.

Comment: Most if not all solutions presented there can be applied here. This is such a basic problem, that you probably wouldn't even need those. I suggest you try the Boolean approach as it is the easiest and gives you visual feedback how it works. My solution would be to extrude the face marking the hole to the other side of the first wall, delete the large face and then create faces as on the outside.

Comment: Inset both faces of the part of the cube through which hole should be cut (one of those faces is in place already on screenshot above), move insetted faces down where need be, run Bridge Edge Loops operator (all without deselecting the insetted faces), that should be it